# Get error ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE when attempting to stream video from Node.JS server with pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, video-streaming, pipeline

I'm attempting to stream a video from a server to the browser using the pipeline function of the stream library. It's a fairly large video (88.7MB), which means I want to stream it to the browser in 5MB chunks. I created the server following some tutorials online, however I notice that there is some weird behaviour where streams are being prematurely closed (because the browser decides that it wants the very last part of the video before the first part has even been sent).

This is the output:

```
21:01:29.215   Server is running on http://192.168.1.180:80
21:01:33.562   --------------------------------- New Request ---------------------------------
21:01:33.563   No range specified.
21:01:33.624   --------------------------------- New Request ---------------------------------
21:01:33.625   ( 1 )  Starting Pipe  | Browser requested:  bytes=0-  | Start:  0  | End:  5242880  | Content Length:  5242881  | Content Range:  bytes 0-5242880/93008043  | Video Size:  93008043
21:01:33.625   ( 1 )  Pipeline created
21:01:33.710   --------------------------------- New Request ---------------------------------
21:01:33.710   ( 2 )  Starting Pipe  | Browser requested:  bytes=92798976-  | Start:  92798976  | End:  93008042  | Content Length:  209067  | Content Range:  bytes 92798976-93008042/93008043  | Video Size:  93008043
21:01:33.711   ( 2 )  Pipeline created
21:01:33.711   ( 1 )  Pipeline error:  
21:01:33.711   Error [ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE]: Premature close
                   at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
                   at ServerResponse.onclose (node:internal/streams/end-of-stream:139:30)
                   at ServerResponse.emit (node:events:532:35)
                   at emitCloseNT (node:_http_server:845:10)
                   at Socket.onServerResponseClose (node:_http_server:233:5)
                   at Socket.emit (node:events:532:35)
                   at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)
                   at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)

21:01:33.715   ( 2 )  Pipeline success
```

As you can see form above, the browser initially requests for the first bytes of the video yet 60ms later (before the data has even been sent) it creates a second pipeline request for the very last parts of the video (?) which makes no sense. This causes the first pipeline to error, and I don't know how to fix this. (Sending smaller chunks is not an option).

Another thing I have noticed is that it doesn't send all of the data as quickly as possible, all it does is wait until browser says it wants more data (instead of sending right away)

I haven't noticed this error appearing when other devices try to watch the video at the same time (or watching from multiple tabs) so I am wondering if this is caused because it can't create two pipelines to the same tab/device/source.

Here is my server code:

```
const http = require("http");
const path = require("path");
const { statSync, createReadStream } = require("fs");
const { pipeline } = require("stream")
const print = require("./../../mods/print.js")

const host = "192.168.1.180";
const port = 80;

let pipe_number = 0;
let chunk_size = 1024*1024*5
let video_path = path.normalize(__dirname + "/video.mp4")

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    print(`--------------------------------- New Request ---------------------------------`)
    const { range } = req.headers
    const { size } = statSync(video_path)
    if (range) {
        pipe_number++
        let this_pipe = pipe_number
        const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")
        const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10)
        const end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : Math.min(start + chunk_size, size - 1)
        
        const content_length = (end-start) + 1
        const head = {
            "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${size}`,
            "Accept-Ranges": `bytes`,
            "Content-Length": content_length,
            "Content-Type": `video/mp4`
        };
        print(`( ${this_pipe} )`, `Starting Pipe`, "| Browser requested:", range, "| Start:", start, "| End:", end, "| Content Length:", content_length, "| Content Range:", `bytes ${start}-${end}/${size}`,"| Video Size:", size)

        const file = createReadStream(video_path, {start, end})

        res.writeHead(206, head);

        print(`( ${this_pipe} )`, "Pipeline created")
        pipeline(file, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                print(`( ${this_pipe} )`, "Pipeline error:", err)
            } else {
                print(`( ${this_pipe} )`, "Pipeline success")
        }
    })
    } else {
        print("No range specified.")
        const head = {
            'Content-Length': 0,
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
        };
        res.writeHead(200, head)
        res.end()
    }
}).listen(port, host, () => {print(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`)})
```

I got most of this from online tutorials because of course this is something new to me. I am not using express.js here either.

Answer (score 1):

You might have found the issue by now but for future googlers, I was having this issue and it turned out incorrect content was written to the response (the start/end bytes weren't present so the whole file was being written).

Also https://github.com/vercel/serve-handler/blob/master/src/index.js has a good reference for how to return 206/416 responses correctly.